# Forking inside conditional statements

Tags: c++, operating-system, fork

How would I calculate how many "hello world" are printed after the execution of this program. Based on how fork works, we know that fork returns non-zero value as a parent process, and a child process returns 0.

I have worked with fork() before, and calculating fork count when in loops, but have not done anything with conditional statements, how would I begin to break this problem down?

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    (fork() && fork() || fork() && fork() || fork() && fork() && fork());
    printf("hello world");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Trick question, this code never prints `hello world`, it prints only `a` ;)

Comment: I think it's easiest to draw a tree of spawned child processes and evaluate the chain for each process to see when they break out due to short-circuiting.

Comment: You should start with something easier, like `fork() && fork();`.

Comment: Not that I endorse such problems, but you can start by converting everything to nested `if(...)`.

Comment: probably you should start adding an actual `if`

Comment: @Federico it works without if

Comment: Note that `if` evaluation is optimized and may stop as soon as it has a definite conclusion. So not all fork() calls you write will have to be actually executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To better understand what's going on you should try to draw a tree with parent and children processes.

Consider that after a fork():

- the parent process return a number > 0
- child process return a number == 0

that means:

- && operator allows multiple children for the same parent because as soon as the pid=0 (child process) the result is 0 and the condition is no longer considered
- || operator allows single child for the parent processes because as soon as the pid!=0 (parent process) the result is !=0 and the condition is no longer considered

Visualizing the trees related with much simpler cases than yours:

fork() && fork() && fork()

```
                                  P
                                / | \
                              C1 C2 C3
```

fork() || fork() || fork()

```
                                      P
                                     /
                                    C1
                                   /
                                  C2
                                 /
                               C3
```

As a suggestion, if you want to understand more about what's going on and be able to build the tree, replace your printf() with:

```
printf("hello world - pid %d, ppid %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
```

so you can understand more easily how the process tree has been created.